# How does WorkManager work after device is connected to internet in specific scenarios?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am working with WorkManager in android. I want to upload photos when a user gets connected with the network every day otherwise store them offline. Which approach I use to upload photo PeriodicRequest or OneTimeRequest?
If I use PeriodicRequst,then how it works if I set time 2 Hours and user connects to network before 2 hours.How will it work and which time its start?
If I use OneTimeRequest, then how will it work and which time it starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload the photos, periodically, once a day, your best option is to use a [`PeriodicWorkRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest) with a constraint on the network:

```
val myConstraints = Constraints.Builder()
    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
    .build()

val myRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWorker>(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
    .setConstraints(myConstraints)
    .build()

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(myRequest)
```

For more information on how to use recurring work, you can take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work) or watch this [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9r5OCb7Qb8).

Comment: BUT PERIODIC WORK NOT WORKING IN xIAMI MOBILE

Comment: Some OEMs are modifying the Android OS adding additional limitations on the background processes that impact WorkManager functionality.
Please, open a bug on [WorkManager's issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197) adding information on the device model and OS version where you see the problem and, possibily, a small sample demo to reproduce the issue.